# How do I get the share url of a local dropbox file using C#

Tags: c#, dropbox, dropnet

I am using the DropNet API to retrieve the share link of a local file but cannot get past the GetAccessToken() because it is null.

Here is my code so far:

```
var _client = new DropNetClient(APIKEY, APISEC);
_client.GetToken();
var url = _client.BuildAuthorizeUrl();
Process.Start(url);
var accessToken = _client.GetAccessToken();                    
var shareResponse = _client.GetShare("/Getting Started.rtf");
MessageBox.Show(shareResponse.Url);
```

exception thrown at GetShare():

```
System.Reflection.TargetInvocationException
```

It has to be something with how I am launching the browser but I've been at this for hours, thanks for any help!

Answer (score 1):

After hours and hours I finally found decent documentation from Spring.Social (from NuGet).

Here it is:

1. Sign up for a new app to link to your program here: [DropBox / Developer / Apps](https://www.dropbox.com/developers/apps)
2. Install the NuGet Package Spring.Social.Dropbox.
3. Use the example below to connect.

   ```
   using Spring.Social.Dropbox.Api;
   using Spring.Social.Dropbox.Connect;
   using Spring.Social.OAuth1;

   private void ShareViaDropbox(string[,] filesNameLink)
   {
       try
       {
           if (CheckForInternetConnection()) // cant use dropbox without internet.
           {
               string consumerKey = "<get this from dropbox>";
               string consumerSecret = "<get this from dropbox>";

               DropboxServiceProvider dropboxServiceProvider = new DropboxServiceProvider(consumerKey, consumerSecret, AccessLevel.Full);
               IOAuth1Operations oauthOperations = dropboxServiceProvider.OAuthOperations;

               // I used an xml file to store the key (probably not the most secure later I will write an encryption).
               string[] storedToken = GetTag("<DropBoxToken>", ",").Split(','); 
               OAuthToken oauthAccessToken = new OAuthToken(storedToken[0], storedToken[1]);

               // testing if we got something from the earlier xml tag.
               if (oauthAccessToken.Value == string.Empty || oauthAccessToken.Value == "") 
               {
                   Console.Write("Getting request token...");
                   OAuthToken oauthToken = dropboxServiceProvider.OAuthOperations.FetchRequestTokenAsync(null, null).Result;
                   Console.WriteLine("Done");
                   OAuth1Parameters parameters = new OAuth1Parameters();
                   string authenticateUrl = dropboxServiceProvider.OAuthOperations.BuildAuthorizeUrl(oauthToken.Value, parameters);

                   Console.WriteLine("Redirect user for authorization");

                   // let the user know they have to sign in and chose the correct dropbox. this is also where most documentation leaves off! 
                   MessageBox.Show(
                       "This is the first time you have connected to DropBox. A browser will open and direct you the the DropBox authentication page. When you prompted, please sign in and then choose the [named] DropBox." + Environment.NewLine +
                       "Once you have succesfully compleaded the authorization confirmation from DropBox, you may close the browser to continue." + Environment.NewLine +
                       Environment.NewLine +
                       "Click 'Ok' to proceed", "DropBox Authentication Required.", MessageBoxButtons.OK, MessageBoxIcon.Information);
                   Process.Start(authenticateUrl);

                   // halt the program until the user has authenticated.
                   MessageBox.Show("Click 'OK' when authorization has succeeded.", "DropBox Authentication - WAIT", MessageBoxButtons.OK, MessageBoxIcon.Stop);
                   Console.Write("Press any key when authorization attempt has succeeded");
                   Console.Write("Getting access token...");
                   AuthorizedRequestToken requestToken = new AuthorizedRequestToken(oauthToken, null);
                   oauthAccessToken = dropboxServiceProvider.OAuthOperations.ExchangeForAccessTokenAsync(requestToken, null).Result;
                   Console.WriteLine("Done");
                   ChangeTag("<DropBoxToken>", oauthAccessToken.Value + "," + oauthAccessToken.Secret); // update the xml file with the token.                        
               }

               IDropbox dropbox = dropboxServiceProvider.GetApi(oauthAccessToken.Value, oauthAccessToken.Secret);
               DropboxLink shareableLink;
               double filesNameLength = Math.Ceiling(Convert.ToDouble(filesNameLink.Length / 2));

               // remove everything before the users special folder path including the dropbbox folder.
               // then change all the switches to front from back for the web.
               for (int i = 0; i < filesNameLength; i++)
               {
                   filesNameLink[i, 1] = filesNameLink[i, 0];
                   filesNameLink[i, 0] = Path.GetFileName(filesNameLink[i, 0]);
                   filesNameLink[i, 1] = filesNameLink[i, 1].Replace(dropboxRootDir, "").Replace("\\", "/");
                   shareableLink = dropbox.GetShareableLinkAsync(filesNameLink[i, 1].Replace("\\", "/")).Result;
                   filesNameLink[i, 1] = shareableLink.Url;
               }
               // do something with the link(s). //
               catch { }
           }
       }
       catch { }
   }
   ```